# WPF Datagrid 'CurrentItem' property not taking updated values from datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

hope you are well!

[Youtube video of my problem](https://youtu.be/yweHA8rEv1s)

As you can see in the short video (49 seconds), when I change a value in the datagrid and click the update button the datagrid.CurrentItem doesn't have the changed value but when I update it for the second time and I first click outside the datagrid row and then click the update button it works... I have tried an observable collection (a colleague suggested, but I have never worked with them before and as far as I can see it made no difference. The collection didn't even update.)

Thanks for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic "edit mode" problem.  In the first take, the cell is in "edit mode", and has not yet committed the value to the row.  In the second take, you click off, allowing the cell's editor to validate and commit.  That's the only difference.

So, if you want to be able to support the first behavior, you need to add a line to the button click handler to validate the row.

Something like this, perhaps:

```
rowBeingEdited.EndEdit();
```

I don't think an `ObservableCollection` would solve anything, because it is not a data store problem, it is a problem with the editor not realizing that you are done with the edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! While I couldn't get that line to work (had trouble selecting the current row...) your answer pointed me in the right direction. I changed the xaml on each column to `<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding EmpStatus, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Active" >` UpdateSourceTrigger worked perfect!